# Как затемнить нижнюю часть изображения?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

!DOCTYPE html>

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lemon</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/caaa6ed519.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lemon.css">
</head>
<body>//
```

//////////

Comment: добавить поверх блок с градиентом

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я тоже склонялся к градиенту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуй сделать див с этим параметром поверх изображения

```css
.blacker_blur {
    margin-top: 60px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, black -15%, transparent 90%);
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
```

```html
<div class="blacker_blur"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, были сомнения, благодаря ответу рассеялись.

Answer (score 2):

Ты можешь использовать псевдо элемент "div::after" и задать градиент

```html
div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(img);
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, black);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]